# Including error bars on graph in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

[image]

Mathematica ListPlot function allows me to plot the above data with omega on the x-axis and CD on the y-axis

[image]

1) How do I incorporate the error bars in my data on the graph?
2) Are there any basis statistical analysis I could possibly extract from my exists data table?

Comment: Try ``Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]``

Comment: Look up "error bars" on this site and in Mathematica's documentation. Many hits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
MyData = {{0.5, 0.476}, {0.8, 0.55}, {1.15, 0.703}, {1.3, 0.733}};
error = {0.009, 0.03, 0.003, 0.015};
withError = Transpose[{MyData[[All, 1]], MyData[[All, 2]], error}]
```

> {{0.5, 0.476, 0.009}, {0.8, 0.55, 0.03}, {1.15, 0.703, 0.003}, {1.3, 
>     0.733, 0.015}}

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
Show[ListPlot[MyData], Plot[lm[x], {x, 0, 5}],ErrorListPlot[withError,
PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

See also: [ErrorListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html)

Comment: Hi Lou,
It is strange that when I plot using your codes, the best-fit line is not showing.

Comment: @boyinneed, do you execute the linear Model fit?

Comment: Yes I do. Thank you (: